# Can't call method coordinateToPrice()

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

Can't call method coordinateToPrice(), as it is written in the documentation

[Doc](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/34d47b87afb6c60028f21b083c6059741c81c6fb/docs/series-basics.md)

But some other method, like series.options() work fine.

This is my code:

```
    const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});
let series = chart.addLineSeries();

    series.setData([
    { time: '2018-12-12', value: 24.11 },
    { time: '2018-12-13', value: 31.74 },
]);
let price = series.coordinateToPrice(2);
```

And error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: series.coordinateToPrice is not a function

Comment: You have `series.coordinateToPrice` in code but error has `chart.coordinateToPrice` part.
Looks like you call the function from `chart` object and not `series`.

Comment: My mistake, fixed

Comment: It's not work yet